# How to track specific client requests on a server?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to track the call for opening a file and then initiating a new thread to handle the request. How is it possible to trap a specific request from a client such as opening a certain file on a server in VB.net ?
I have looked up the WebRequest class. But it doesn't seem to meet my requirements. How can I solve my problem using something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that handles file requests.

```
Sub GetFile(path as string)
    'Do something to log the file request
    'Now process the file request
End Sub
```